# Can commensurate be used as a transitive verb?

Tags: verbs, transitive-verbs

I need to make two datasets commensurate.  Can I "commensurate" them?

Comment: @JohnClifford - Since I found it in my large dead-tree OED (whose sheer mass makes it about as "official" as you can get, short of reanimating the ghost of Samuel Johnson) I went ahead and made it an "answer." I agree though, that it's not a locution I'd live to love.  Cheers!

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want to say, maybe "reconcile" would meet your needs. I say this mostly because, like others, I happen to to like the sound of commensurate as a transitive verb.

Comment: wouldn't _condition them_ work?

Comment: **commensurate** - *corresponding in size or degree; in proportion. synonyms: **equivalent, equal, corresponding,** correspondent, comparable, proportionate, proportional.* You might consider ***equalize*** (or perhaps ***normalize*** if you're using *commensurate* more loosely to mean "easily compared, having similar values in the same units of measure"). But OED has as definition 2 for the verb **commensurate**: *(trans.) To make commensurate; to proportion; to make to correspond in nature.*

Answer (score 1):

According to the OED, you can.  It lists a transitive definition of **commensurate** with a citation in 1655.  If you wish to *"proportion, or make to correspond in nature"*, then this is your word.

**Caveat:**

Just because this use of **commensurate** appears in the OED, don't feel compelled to adopt it, however.

The [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+commensurate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20commensurate%3B%2Cc0) shows a frequency of 0.000001% for the infinitive *"to commensurate*" - not an altogether fair snapshot, but enough to suggest that one uses the word as a verb at the peril of having it questioned here on EL&U or by even higher authorities.

Comment: If I were going to use any verb for this, I'd probably use "proportion" as that is a better-known more commonly-used one. Good find, though, +1.

Comment: Several of those ngram hits are of the form *incommensurate-to-commensurate* and *entitled to commensurate wages*. These are not transitive forms, so I'll take the invitation and question the proposed usage.